# iphone FullScreen navigation bar displacement

Tags: iphone, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I implemented an app Images in full screen are displayed fine.

After few seconds the navigation bar and status bar are hidden, now if i close the app and again open it, the navigation bar is displaced at the top of the screen where status bar overlaps on navigation bar

I guess i have to change something about the CGRect frame

Please help me

```
#import "KTPhotoScrollViewController.h"
#import "KTPhotoBrowserDataSource.h"
#import "KTPhotoBrowserGlobal.h"
#import "KTPhotoView.h"

const CGFloat ktkDefaultPortraitToolbarHeight   = 44;
const CGFloat ktkDefaultLandscapeToolbarHeight  = 33;
const CGFloat ktkDefaultToolbarHeight = 44;

#define BUTTON_DELETEPHOTO 0
#define BUTTON_CANCEL 1

@interface KTPhotoScrollViewController (KTPrivate)
- (void)setCurrentIndex:(NSInteger)newIndex;
- (void)toggleChrome:(BOOL)hide;
- (void)startChromeDisplayTimer;
- (void)cancelChromeDisplayTimer;
- (void)hideChrome;
- (void)showChrome;
- (void)swapCurrentAndNextPhotos;
- (void)nextPhoto;
- (void)previousPhoto;
- (void)toggleNavButtons;
- (CGRect)frameForPagingScrollView;
- (CGRect)frameForPageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)loadPhoto:(NSInteger)index;
- (void)unloadPhoto:(NSInteger)index;
- (void)trashPhoto;
- (void)exportPhoto;
@end

@implementation KTPhotoScrollViewController

@synthesize statusBarStyle = statusBarStyle_;
@synthesize statusbarHidden = statusbarHidden_;
@synthesize my_img, imgURL;

- (void)dealloc 
{
   [nextButton_ release], nextButton_ = nil;
   [previousButton_ release], previousButton_ = nil;
   [scrollView_ release], scrollView_ = nil;
   [toolbar_ release], toolbar_ = nil;
   [photoViews_ release], photoViews_ = nil;
   [dataSource_ release], dataSource_ = nil;  
   [super dealloc];
}

- (id)initWithDataSource:(id <KTPhotoBrowserDataSource>)dataSource andStartWithPhotoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index 
{
   if (self = [super init]) {
     startWithIndex_ = index;
     dataSource_ = [dataSource retain];

     // Make sure to set wantsFullScreenLayout or the photo
     // will not display behind the status bar.
     [self setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];

     BOOL isStatusbarHidden = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] isStatusBarHidden];
     [self setStatusbarHidden:isStatusbarHidden];

     self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
   }
   return self;
}

- (void)loadView 
{
   [super loadView];

   CGRect scrollFrame = [self frameForPagingScrollView];
   UIScrollView *newView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollFrame];
   [newView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
   [newView setDelegate:self];

   UIColor *backgroundColor = [dataSource_ respondsToSelector:@selector(imageBackgroundColor)] ?
                                [dataSource_ imageBackgroundColor] : [UIColor blackColor];  
   [newView setBackgroundColor:backgroundColor];
   [newView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
   [newView setPagingEnabled:YES];
   [newView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
   [newView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];

   [[self view] addSubview:newView];

   scrollView_ = [newView retain];

   [newView release];

   nextButton_ = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                  initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nextIcon.png"]
                  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                  target:self
                  action:@selector(nextPhoto)];

   previousButton_ = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                      initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"previousIcon.png"]
                      style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                      target:self
                      action:@selector(previousPhoto)];

    UIBarButtonItem *msgButton = nil;
    UIBarButtonItem *exportButton = nil;

    exportButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction 
                                                                 target:self
                                                                 action:@selector(exportPhoto)];

    msgButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks 
                                                                 target:self
                                                                 action:@selector(msgPhoto)];

//    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-Small"];
//    UIButton *myMuteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
//    myMuteButton.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height );    
//    [myMuteButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//    [myMuteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(trashPhoto) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
//    UIBarButtonItem *myMuteBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myMuteButton];   


    UIBarItem *space = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    NSMutableArray *toolbarItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:7];

    if (exportButton) [toolbarItems addObject:exportButton];

    [toolbarItems addObject:space];
    [toolbarItems addObject:previousButton_];
    [toolbarItems addObject:space];
    [toolbarItems addObject:nextButton_];
    [toolbarItems addObject:space];

     if (msgButton) [toolbarItems addObject:msgButton];

//    [toolbarItems addObject:myMuteBarButtonItem];
//    [myMuteBarButtonItem release];

    CGRect screenFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGRect toolbarFrame = CGRectMake(0, 
                                     screenFrame.size.height - ktkDefaultToolbarHeight, 
                                     screenFrame.size.width, 
                                     ktkDefaultToolbarHeight);
    toolbar_ = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:toolbarFrame];
    [toolbar_ setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];
    [toolbar_ setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
    [toolbar_ setItems:toolbarItems];
    [[self view] addSubview:toolbar_];

    if (msgButton) [msgButton release];
    if (exportButton) [exportButton release];
    [toolbarItems release];
    [space release];
}

- (void) ShowAlert:(NSString*)title MyMsg:(NSString*)msg{
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert autorelease];   
}

- (void)setTitleWithCurrentPhotoIndex 
{
   NSString *formatString = NSLocalizedString(@"%1$i of %2$i", @"Picture X out of Y total.");
   NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:formatString, currentIndex_ + 1, photoCount_, nil];
   [self setTitle:title];
}

- (void)scrollToIndex:(NSInteger)index 
{
   CGRect frame = scrollView_.frame;
   frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * index;
   frame.origin.y = 0;
   [scrollView_ scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:NO];
}

- (void)setScrollViewContentSize
{
   NSInteger pageCount = photoCount_;
   if (pageCount == 0) {
      pageCount = 1;
   }

   CGSize size = CGSizeMake(scrollView_.frame.size.width * pageCount, 
                            scrollView_.frame.size.height / 2);   // Cut in half to prevent horizontal scrolling.
   [scrollView_ setContentSize:size];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   photoCount_ = [dataSource_ numberOfPhotos];
   [self setScrollViewContentSize];

   // Setup our photo view cache. We only keep 3 views in
   // memory. NSNull is used as a placeholder for the other
   // elements in the view cache array.
   photoViews_ = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:photoCount_];
   for (int i=0; i < photoCount_; i++) {
      [photoViews_ addObject:[NSNull null]];
   }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning 
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];

   // The first time the view appears, store away the previous controller's values so we can reset on pop.
   UINavigationBar *navbar = [[self navigationController] navigationBar];
   if (!viewDidAppearOnce_) {
      viewDidAppearOnce_ = YES;
      navbarWasTranslucent_ = [navbar isTranslucent];
      statusBarStyle_ = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarStyle];
   }
   // Then ensure translucency. Without it, the view will appear below rather than under it.  
   [navbar setTranslucent:YES];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent animated:YES];

   // Set the scroll view's content size, auto-scroll to the stating photo,
   // and setup the other display elements.
   [self setScrollViewContentSize];
   [self setCurrentIndex:startWithIndex_];
   [self scrollToIndex:startWithIndex_];

   [self setTitleWithCurrentPhotoIndex];
   [self toggleNavButtons];
   [self startChromeDisplayTimer];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
  // Reset nav bar translucency and status bar style to whatever it was before.
  UINavigationBar *navbar = [[self navigationController] navigationBar];
  [navbar setTranslucent:navbarWasTranslucent_];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:statusBarStyle_ animated:YES];
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
   [self cancelChromeDisplayTimer];
   [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)deleteCurrentPhoto 
{
   if (dataSource_) {
      // TODO: Animate the deletion of the current photo.

      NSInteger photoIndexToDelete = currentIndex_;
      [self unloadPhoto:photoIndexToDelete];
      [dataSource_ deleteImageAtIndex:photoIndexToDelete];

      photoCount_ -= 1;
      if (photoCount_ == 0) {
         [self showChrome];
         [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
      } else {
         NSInteger nextIndex = photoIndexToDelete;
         if (nextIndex == photoCount_) {
            nextIndex -= 1;
         }
         [self setCurrentIndex:nextIndex];
         [self setScrollViewContentSize];
      }
   }
}

- (void)toggleNavButtons 
{
   [previousButton_ setEnabled:(currentIndex_ > 0)];
   [nextButton_ setEnabled:(currentIndex_ < photoCount_ - 1)];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Frame calculations
#define PADDING  20

- (CGRect)frameForPagingScrollView 
{
   CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
   frame.origin.x -= PADDING;
   frame.size.width += (2 * PADDING);
   return frame;
}

- (CGRect)frameForPageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index 
{
   CGRect bounds = [scrollView_ bounds];
   CGRect pageFrame = bounds;
   pageFrame.size.width -= (2 * PADDING);
   pageFrame.origin.x = (bounds.size.width * index) + PADDING;
   return pageFrame;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Photo (Page) Management

- (void)loadPhoto:(NSInteger)index
{
   if (index < 0 || index >= photoCount_) {
      return;
   }

   id currentPhotoView = [photoViews_ objectAtIndex:index];
   if (NO == [currentPhotoView isKindOfClass:[KTPhotoView class]]) {
      // Load the photo view.
      CGRect frame = [self frameForPageAtIndex:index];
      KTPhotoView *photoView = [[KTPhotoView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
      [photoView setScroller:self];
      [photoView setIndex:index];
      [photoView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

      // Set the photo image.
      if (dataSource_) {
         if ([dataSource_ respondsToSelector:@selector(imageAtIndex:photoView:)] == NO) {
            UIImage *image = [dataSource_ imageAtIndex:index];
            [photoView setImage:image];
         } else {
            [dataSource_ imageAtIndex:index photoView:photoView];
         }
      }

      [scrollView_ addSubview:photoView];
      [photoViews_ replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:photoView];
      [photoView release];
   } else {
      // Turn off zooming.
      [currentPhotoView turnOffZoom];
   }
}

- (void)unloadPhoto:(NSInteger)index
{
   if (index < 0 || index >= photoCount_) {
      return;
   }

   id currentPhotoView = [photoViews_ objectAtIndex:index];
   if ([currentPhotoView isKindOfClass:[KTPhotoView class]]) {
      [currentPhotoView removeFromSuperview];
      [photoViews_ replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:[NSNull null]];
   }
}

- (void)setCurrentIndex:(NSInteger)newIndex
{
   currentIndex_ = newIndex;

    if(newIndex>=0){
        myUrl   = [dataSource_ imageURLAtIndex:currentIndex_ photoView:[photoViews_ objectAtIndex:currentIndex_]];
        myDescr = [dataSource_ imageDESCRAtIndex:currentIndex_ photoView:[photoViews_ objectAtIndex:currentIndex_]];
        img_Title =[dataSource_ imageimg_TitleAtIndex:currentIndex_ photoView:[photoViews_ objectAtIndex:currentIndex_]];
    }

   [self loadPhoto:currentIndex_];
   [self loadPhoto:currentIndex_ + 1];
   [self loadPhoto:currentIndex_ - 1];
   [self unloadPhoto:currentIndex_ + 2];
   [self unloadPhoto:currentIndex_ - 2];

   [self setTitleWithCurrentPhotoIndex];
   [self toggleNavButtons];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Rotation Magic

- (void)updateToolbarWithOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
   CGRect toolbarFrame = toolbar_.frame;
   if ((interfaceOrientation) == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || (interfaceOrientation) == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
      toolbarFrame.size.height = ktkDefaultPortraitToolbarHeight;
   } else {
      toolbarFrame.size.height = ktkDefaultLandscapeToolbarHeight+1;
   }

   toolbarFrame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width;
   toolbarFrame.origin.y =  self.view.frame.size.height - toolbarFrame.size.height;
   toolbar_.frame = toolbarFrame;
}

- (void)layoutScrollViewSubviews
{
   [self setScrollViewContentSize];

   NSArray *subviews = [scrollView_ subviews];

   for (KTPhotoView *photoView in subviews) {
      CGPoint restorePoint = [photoView pointToCenterAfterRotation];
      CGFloat restoreScale = [photoView scaleToRestoreAfterRotation];
      [photoView setFrame:[self frameForPageAtIndex:[photoView index]]];
      [photoView setMaxMinZoomScalesForCurrentBounds];
      [photoView restoreCenterPoint:restorePoint scale:restoreScale];
   }

   // adjust contentOffset to preserve page location based on values collected prior to location
   CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView_.bounds.size.width;
   CGFloat newOffset = (firstVisiblePageIndexBeforeRotation_ * pageWidth) + (percentScrolledIntoFirstVisiblePage_ * pageWidth);
   scrollView_.contentOffset = CGPointMake(newOffset, 0);

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
   return YES;
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation 
                                duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
{
   // here, our pagingScrollView bounds have not yet been updated for the new interface orientation. So this is a good
   // place to calculate the content offset that we will need in the new orientation
   CGFloat offset = scrollView_.contentOffset.x;
   CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView_.bounds.size.width;

   if (offset >= 0) {
      firstVisiblePageIndexBeforeRotation_ = floorf(offset / pageWidth);
      percentScrolledIntoFirstVisiblePage_ = (offset - (firstVisiblePageIndexBeforeRotation_ * pageWidth)) / pageWidth;
   } else {
      firstVisiblePageIndexBeforeRotation_ = 0;
      percentScrolledIntoFirstVisiblePage_ = offset / pageWidth;
   }    

}

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                                         duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
{
   [self layoutScrollViewSubviews];
   // Rotate the toolbar.
   [self updateToolbarWithOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];

   // Adjust navigation bar if needed.
   if (isChromeHidden_ && statusbarHidden_ == NO) {
      UINavigationBar *navbar = [[self navigationController] navigationBar];
      CGRect frame = [navbar frame];
      frame.origin.y = 20;
      [navbar setFrame:frame];
   }
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation 
{
   [self startChromeDisplayTimer];
}

- (UIView *)rotatingFooterView 
{
   return toolbar_;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Chrome Helpers

- (void)toggleChromeDisplay 
{
   [self toggleChrome:!isChromeHidden_];
}

- (void)toggleChrome:(BOOL)hide 
{
   isChromeHidden_ = hide;
   if (hide) {
      [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
      [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
   }

   if ( ! [self isStatusbarHidden] ) {     
     if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:)]) {
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:hide withAnimation:NO];
     } else {  // Deprecated in iOS 3.2+.
       id sharedApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];  // Get around deprecation warnings.
       [sharedApp setStatusBarHidden:hide animated:NO];
     }
   }

   CGFloat alpha = hide ? 0.0 : 1.0;

   // Must set the navigation bar's alpha, otherwise the photo
   // view will be pushed until the navigation bar.
   UINavigationBar *navbar = [[self navigationController] navigationBar];
   [navbar setAlpha:alpha];

   [toolbar_ setAlpha:alpha];

   if (hide) {
      [UIView commitAnimations];
   }

   if ( ! isChromeHidden_ ) {
      [self startChromeDisplayTimer];
   }
}

- (void)hideChrome 
{
   if (chromeHideTimer_ && [chromeHideTimer_ isValid]) {
      [chromeHideTimer_ invalidate];
      chromeHideTimer_ = nil;
   }
   [self toggleChrome:YES];
}

- (void)showChrome 
{
   [self toggleChrome:NO];
}

- (void)startChromeDisplayTimer 
{
   [self cancelChromeDisplayTimer];
   chromeHideTimer_ = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                                                       target:self 
                                                     selector:@selector(hideChrome)
                                                     userInfo:nil
                                                      repeats:NO];
}

- (void)cancelChromeDisplayTimer 
{
   if (chromeHideTimer_) {
      [chromeHideTimer_ invalidate];
      chromeHideTimer_ = nil;
   }
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIScrollViewDelegate

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{
   CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
   float fractionalPage = scrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;
   NSInteger page = floor(fractionalPage);
    if (page != currentIndex_) {
        [self setCurrentIndex:page];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{
   [self hideChrome];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Toolbar Actions

- (void)nextPhoto 
{
   [self scrollToIndex:currentIndex_ + 1];
   [self startChromeDisplayTimer];
}

- (void)previousPhoto 
{
   [self scrollToIndex:currentIndex_ - 1];
   [self startChromeDisplayTimer];
}

- (void)msgPhoto 
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:img_Title message:myDescr  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

- (void)imageSavedToPhotosAlbum:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo {  

    NSString *message;  
    NSString *title;  
    if (!error) {  
        title = @"Done";  
        message = @"image copied to your local gallery";  
    } else {  
        title = @"Error";  
        message = [error description];  
    }  
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];  
    [alert show];  
    [alert release];  
}  


- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        //save to gallery
        UIImage *imageB = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: myUrl]]];
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageB, self, @selector(imageSavedToPhotosAlbum: didFinishSavingWithError: contextInfo:), nil);

    } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        //email

        MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        mailComposer.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
        mailComposer.title = @"Your title here";
        [[mailComposer navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:124.0/255 green:17.0/255 blue:92.0/255 alpha:1]]; 

        if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

            [mailComposer setSubject:@"Look at a great image"];
            [mailComposer setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",myUrl] isHTML:NO];

            UIImage *imageB = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: myUrl]]];
            NSData *exportData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageB ,1.0);
            [mailComposer addAttachmentData:exportData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:img_Title];

            [self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
        }

        //release the mailComposer as it is now being managed as the UIViewControllers modalViewController.
        [mailComposer release];

    } else if (buttonIndex == 2) {
        //cancel

    }

    [self startChromeDisplayTimer];
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    if (result == MFMailComposeResultFailed) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to send message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}

- (void) exportPhoto
{ 

    if ([dataSource_ respondsToSelector:@selector(exportImageAtIndex:)])
        [dataSource_ exportImageAtIndex:currentIndex_];

    [self startChromeDisplayTimer];

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Actions"
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Save to gallery", @"Email",nil];
    [actionSheet showInView:[self view]];
    [actionSheet release];     
}

@end
```

Comment: Can you edit down the code you have posted to show what you think is relevant to the problem?

Comment: the problem is i don't know.. i'm sorry... i've read that the problem might be in CGRect frame! I'm sorry, i don't know where to look, i am totally new..

Comment: One way to work out if any given code might have influence on a problem is to use NSLog's to find out if a given bit of code is being called. If it isn't then you can assume that it isn't relevant to this problem (unless, of course, you are expecting the code to be called and it isn't ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, tel me if you want to show Status Bar or not.

If you dont want to show then, in **nib** of **controller's**, you can select its **view**, and under its properties set **StatusBar** to **NONE**, thar time it wont show status bar... and you can set vew size to (320*480) or else with status bar it will be (320*460) and 20 pixels will be reserved for status bar.

Other ways to do (without using above method)

Can hide StatusBar from **info.plist** also, by setting property **UIStatusBarHidden** property to **YES**. (To hide the status bar when the app launches)

Programmatically can be done, add line to appDelegate's **applicationDidFinishLaunching** method,

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

Comment: Hello dear, i just wanted to say thank you! you have "saved" me :)

Comment: It's so simple and we all got in depth of coding and find out what is in side the coding, but it's just design problem lols :) ;)